# Passing multiple variables through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following Javascript functions, where each one add a variable to the URL, and I would like to combine them:

```
<script>
function showDuration(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "Loading Please Wait";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?duration="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

function showDelivery(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "Loading Please Wait";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?delivery="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Its problematic, because both variable needs to be present in the url, or else, i get an error for the one that's not selected. More precisely, I would like to combine:

```
      xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?delivery="+str,true);
```

and

```
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?duration="+str,true);
```

Thanks in advance, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

update

```
var duration = null;
var delivery = null;

function setDuration(_duration) {
  duration = _duration;
  makeRequest();
}
function setDelivery(_delivery) {
  delivery = _delivery;
  makeRequest();
}
function makeRequest() {
  if (duration != null && delivery != null) {
    var url =
        "getuser.php?duration=" + encodeURIComponent(duration) +
        "&delivery=" + encodeURIComponent(delivery);
    // do the ajaxy stuff
  }
}
function showDuration(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "Loading Please Wait";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?duration="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

function showDelivery(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "Loading Please Wait";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?delivery="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

update 2:

```
<script>

var duration = null;
var delivery = null;

function showDuration(_duration) {
  duration = _duration;
  makeRequest();
}
function showDelivery(_delivery) {
  delivery = _delivery;
  makeRequest();
}
function makeRequest() {
  if (duration != null && delivery != null) {
    var url =
        "getuser.php?duration=" + encodeURIComponent(duration) +
        "&delivery=" + encodeURIComponent(delivery);
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url);
        xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
```

Comment: combine the functions and pass 2 parameters?

Comment: thanks for the advice but this where i am struggeling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
var duration = null;
var delivery = null;

function setDuration(_duration) {
  duration = _duration;
  makeRequest();
}
function setDelivery(_delivery) {
  delivery = _delivery;
  makeRequest();
}
function makeRequest() {
  if (duration != null && delivery != null) {
    var url =
        "getuser.php?duration=" + encodeURIComponent(duration) +
        "&delivery=" + encodeURIComponent(delivery);
    // do the ajaxy stuff
  }
}
```

or even better if you encapsulate it so the variables are not exposed.

Comment: and sorry for this newbie question but how would i incorporate this into  my code

Comment: You just replace your functions with these, and replace "do ajaxy stuff" with ajaxy stuff you already had. If you don't know how to encapsulate it, don't worry about it for now; you'd need objects and closures in order to do it, which goes out of the scope of the question.

Comment: I see. but my function is radically different, so I am a bit confused on how I would incorporate it

Comment: What is radically different? My function and your OP functions? Your OP functions and your real functions?

Comment: "replace your functions with these" = "delete your functions and put mine in"; if you want you can rename them to `showDuration` and `showDelivery` instead (not sure why I changed the names). "replace 'do ajaxy stuff' with ajaxy stuff you already had" = "delete the 'do the ajaxy stuff' comment, and insert everything you have from `if (window.XMLHttpRequest)` to `xmlhttp.send()`, replacing the second parameter to `xmlhttp.open` with the new `url` variable".

Comment: Hi sorry, if your not too busy, would you mind having a look at this similar question? Il credit you accordingly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237960/posting-multiple-variable-in-url-and-working-with-checkboxes