# Posting multiple variable in URL and working with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

This is based on the following example:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

The differences are mainly that I am using checkboxes instead of select and where I would want to be able to select multiple items across multiple checkboxes forms:

Below are the two problems I have:

1. I want to be able to post multiple variable in the URL because as of now only one variable can be posted, and I get an error for the one not selected.
2. I want to be able to select multiple checkboxes at once. At its current state you can select multiple checkboxes but the results is only adjusted on the last checkboxes. FOr instance if checkbox 2 + 3 is check only 3 will be displayed, when I would want the result of 2 and 3.

Below is the html portion:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function showUser() {
                var selectedPerson = $('#testform').serialize();
                                                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";


                $.ajax({
                    url:'getuser.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:selectedPerson,
                    success:function(res){
                        $('#txtHint').html(res);
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>

        <script>
            function showUser2() {
                var selectedPerson = $('#testform2').serialize();
                                                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";


                $.ajax({
                    url:'getuser.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:selectedPerson,
                    success:function(res){
                        $('#txtHint').html(res);
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="testform">
            <input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="1">One<br>
            <input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="2">Two<br>
            <input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="3">Three<br>
            <input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="4">Four<br>
            <input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="5">Five<br>
        </form>

        <form id="testform2">
            <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="communication">communication<br>
            <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="business">business<br>
            <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="html and css">Three<br>
            <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="sql">Four<br>
            <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="windows">Five<br>
                      <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="cloud">Cloud<br>
            <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="microsoft office">Java<br>

        </form>

        <br>
        <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the PHP part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
 $person = '';
        $person  = isset($_POST['person']) ? $_POST['person'] : '';
        $allIds = '';
        if($person!=''){
            foreach($person as $personid){
                $allIds .= $personid.',';
            }
            $personid = rtrim($allIds,',');
        }


 $person2 = '';
        $person2  = isset($_POST['person2']) ? $_POST['person2'] : '';
        $allIds = '';
        if($person2!=''){
            foreach($person2 as $personid2){
                $allIds .= $personid2.',';
            }
            $personid2 = rtrim($allIds,',');
        }


include("includes/db.php"); 



global $con;


$sql= "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE (course_duration IN ('" . $personid . "')) OR (course_duration IN ('" . $personid2. "')) LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$sqlCount = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE (course_duration IN ('" . $personid . "')) OR (course_subc1 IN ('" . $personid2. "')) OR (course_subc3 IN ('" . $personid2. "')) OR (course_subc1 IN ('" . $personid2. "')) OR (course_subc4 IN ('" . $personid2. "')) OR (course_subc5 IN ('" . $personid2. "'))";
$get_crs_count = mysqli_query($con, $sqlCount);
$count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($get_crs_count);
echo '<p style="margin-bottom: 8px;margin-top: 8px;font-size:18px;"><b>Number of courses available: </b>' . $count_rows ;
while($row_crs = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

    $crs_id = $row_crs['course_id'];
        $crs_cat = $row_crs['course_cat'];

    $crs_provider = $row_crs['course_provider'];

    $crs_title = $row_crs['course_title'];
        $crs_price = $row_crs['course_price'];
          $crs_city= $row_crs['course_city'];
                      $crs_category= $row_crs['course_cat1'];

          $crs_date= $row_crs['course_date1'];


$crs_sdesc= $row_crs['course_sdesc'];
$crs_shortdesc = mb_strimwidth("$crs_sdesc",0,140,"...");
        $crs_image = $row_crs['course_image'];
        $provider_image = $row_crs['provider_image'];


  echo " <article class='search-result row'><center>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3' id='thumbnailContainer'>
        <a href='#' title='Lorem ipsum' class='thumbnail' id='resultThumbnail'><img src='$provider_image' /></a>
     <a href='searchPage.php?crs_price=$crs_price' style='color:black;'>  <button id='resultprice'><span id='resultpriceText'>$ $crs_price</span></button></a>
      </div>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2'>
        <ul class='meta-search' id='listDesign'>
        <a href='searchPage.php?crs_date=$crs_date' style='color:white;'>   <li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-calendar fa-1x'><span id='iconText'>  $crs_date</span></i></button></li></a>
         <a href='searchPage.php?crs_category=$crs_category' style='color:white;'>   <li><button id='resultInfo2'><i class='fa fa fa-tags fa-1x'><span id='iconText'> $crs_category</span></i></button></li></a>
<a href='searchPage.php?crs_provider=$crs_provider' style='color:white;'><li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-graduation-cap fa-1x'><span id='iconText'>  $crs_provider</span></i></button></li></a>
<a href='searchPage.php?city=$crs_city' style='color:white;'><li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-map-marker fa-1x'><span id='iconText'> $crs_city</span></i></button></li></a>
        </ul>
      </div></center>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 excerpet'>
        <h3 id='resultHeading'><a href='coursePage.php?crs_id=$crs_id' id='headingLinking'><b>$crs_title</b></a></h3>

        <div id='courseshortDescription'>
$crs_shortdesc
 <center><a href='coursePage.php?crs_id=$crs_id' style='color:white;'><button class='btn btn-danger' id='findoutBtn'>Find Out More</button></a> </center>
        </div>  

</div>

      <span class='clearfix borda'></span>
    </article>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Update:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function showUser() {
var selectedPeople = {person: []};
$('input[name="person"]:checked').each(function() {
    selectedPeople.person.push($(this).val());
});                                                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";


                $.ajax({
                    url:'getuser.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:selectedPerson,
                    success:function(res){
                        $('#txtHint').html(res);
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>

        <script>
            function showUser2() {
var selectedPeople = {person2: []};
$('input[name="person2"]:checked').each(function() {
    selectedPeople.person2.push($(this).val());
});                                                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";


                $.ajax({
                    url:'getuser.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:selectedPerson,
                    success:function(res){
                        $('#txtHint').html(res);
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="testform">
            <input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="1">One<br>
            <input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="2">Two<br>
            <input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="3">Three<br>
            <input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="4">Four<br>
            <input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]" type="checkbox" value="5">Five<br>
        </form>

        <form id="testform2">
            <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="communication">communication<br>
            <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="business">business<br>
            <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="html and css">Three<br>
            <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="sql">Four<br>
            <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="windows">Five<br>
                      <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="cloud">Cloud<br>
            <input onchange="showUser2();" name="person2[]" type="checkbox" value="microsoft office">Java<br>

        </form>

        <br>
        <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

the php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$person = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'person', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY);
foreach ($person as $personid)
{
    $allIds .= $personid.',';
}
$personid = rtrim($allIds,',');
       }


$person2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'person2', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY);
foreach ($person2 as $personid2)
{
    $allIds2 .= $personid2.',';
}
$personid2 = rtrim($allIds2,',');
       }


include("includes/db.php"); 



global $con;


$sql= "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE (course_duration IN ('" . $personid . "')) OR (course_duration IN ('" . $personid2. "')) LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$sqlCount = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE (course_duration IN ('" . $personid . "')) OR (course_subc1 IN ('" . $personid2. "')) OR (course_subc3 IN ('" . $personid2. "')) OR (course_subc1 IN ('" . $personid2. "')) OR (course_subc4 IN ('" . $personid2. "')) OR (course_subc5 IN ('" . $personid2. "'))";
$get_crs_count = mysqli_query($con, $sqlCount);
$count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($get_crs_count);
echo '<p style="margin-bottom: 8px;margin-top: 8px;font-size:18px;"><b>Number of courses available: </b>' . $count_rows ;
while($row_crs = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

    $crs_id = $row_crs['course_id'];
        $crs_cat = $row_crs['course_cat'];

    $crs_provider = $row_crs['course_provider'];

    $crs_title = $row_crs['course_title'];
        $crs_price = $row_crs['course_price'];
          $crs_city= $row_crs['course_city'];
                      $crs_category= $row_crs['course_cat1'];

          $crs_date= $row_crs['course_date1'];


$crs_sdesc= $row_crs['course_sdesc'];
$crs_shortdesc = mb_strimwidth("$crs_sdesc",0,140,"...");
        $crs_image = $row_crs['course_image'];
        $provider_image = $row_crs['provider_image'];


  echo " <article class='search-result row'><center>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3' id='thumbnailContainer'>
        <a href='#' title='Lorem ipsum' class='thumbnail' id='resultThumbnail'><img src='$provider_image' /></a>
     <a href='searchPage.php?crs_price=$crs_price' style='color:black;'>  <button id='resultprice'><span id='resultpriceText'>$ $crs_price</span></button></a>
      </div>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2'>
        <ul class='meta-search' id='listDesign'>
        <a href='searchPage.php?crs_date=$crs_date' style='color:white;'>   <li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-calendar fa-1x'><span id='iconText'>  $crs_date</span></i></button></li></a>
         <a href='searchPage.php?crs_category=$crs_category' style='color:white;'>   <li><button id='resultInfo2'><i class='fa fa fa-tags fa-1x'><span id='iconText'> $crs_category</span></i></button></li></a>
<a href='searchPage.php?crs_provider=$crs_provider' style='color:white;'><li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-graduation-cap fa-1x'><span id='iconText'>  $crs_provider</span></i></button></li></a>
<a href='searchPage.php?city=$crs_city' style='color:white;'><li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-map-marker fa-1x'><span id='iconText'> $crs_city</span></i></button></li></a>
        </ul>
      </div></center>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 excerpet'>
        <h3 id='resultHeading'><a href='coursePage.php?crs_id=$crs_id' id='headingLinking'><b>$crs_title</b></a></h3>

        <div id='courseshortDescription'>
$crs_shortdesc
 <center><a href='coursePage.php?crs_id=$crs_id' style='color:white;'><button class='btn btn-danger' id='findoutBtn'>Find Out More</button></a> </center>
        </div>  

</div>

      <span class='clearfix borda'></span>
    </article>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

no errors are shown but what happens when a checkbox is selected, it just stops at this line (found on index js):

```
});                                                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";
```

Comment: i think nothing's wrong, what do you want to achieve ? maybe `print_r($_POST)` in your `getuser.php` should help you understan your array you get. Edit: you should try to use different variable for the second foreach ie ex: `$allIds2` because they mix in your query statements

Comment: thank you, il will try this out. how about for my other problem where i would want that when checkbox 1 + 2 is checked both these results are combined and shown and not just the last  one

Comment: Also change `$personid = rtrim($allIds,',');` to `$allIds = rtrim($allIds,',');`

Comment: thanks i've added an update under my intial post. No errors are shown, but nothing and display upon check and it seems to stop at the following line (loading please wait) });                                                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `var selectedPerson = $('#testform').serialize();` try this:

```
var selectedPeople = {person: []};
$('input[name="person[]"]:checked').each(function() {
    selectedPeople.person.push($(this).val());
});
```

and in your PHP change `$person = ...` to:

```
$person = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'person', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY);
foreach ($person as $personid)
{
    $allIds .= $personid.',';
}
$personid = rtrim($allIds,',');
```

Comment: thanks i've added an update under my intial post. No errors are shown, but nothing and display upon check and it seems to stop at the following line (loading please wait) });                                                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";